# How to add a scroll bar to the following code? (with Tkinter for 2.7.5)

Tags: python, tkinter

Using Tkinter for 2.7.5 I would like to add a scroll bar to the following code, so that all the buttons can be viewed.

Thank you.

Code:

> ```
> import Tkinter, tkMessageBox
>
> root = Tkinter.Tk()
>
> def centerRoot(w = 240, h = 498):  
>     ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
>     hs = root.winfo_screenheight()
>     x = (ws/2) - (w/2)    
>     y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
>     root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
>
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=0,column=0)
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=0,column=1)
>
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=1,column=0)
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=1,column=1)
>
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=2,column=0)
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=2,column=1)
>
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=3,column=0)
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=3,column=1)
>
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=4,column=0)
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=4,column=1)
>
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=5,column=0)
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=5,column=1)
>
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=6,column=0)
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=6,column=1)
>
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=7,column=0)
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=7,column=1)
>
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=8,column=0)
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=8,column=1)
>
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=9,column=0)
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=9,column=1)
>
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=10,column=0)
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=10,column=1)
>
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=11,column=0)
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=11,column=1)
>
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=12,column=0)
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=12,column=1)
>
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=13,column=0)
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=13,column=1)
>
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=14,column=0)
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=14,column=1)
>
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=15,column=0)
> Tkinter.Button(root, height=2, width=10, text='Text', borderwidth=10).grid(row=15,column=1)
>
> centerRoot()
> root.title('Title Here')
> root.mainloop()
> ```

Comment: Check these out - 1. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_scrollbar.htm & 2. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm
and try for yourself! :)

Comment: I would also suggest using a [`for` loop](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=loop#for-statements) to create all those buttons.

Comment: How would I do it in a for loop? an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the buttons in a Canvas since the Canvas widget supports the Scrollbar interface. However, you have to explicitly place the buttons in the Canvas using its window coordinates and not using pack or grid. Here's an example (with a for loop :):

```
import Tkinter


class Application(Tkinter.Frame):
   def __init__(self, master, width, height):
       Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)
       self.master.minsize(width=width, height=height)
       self.master.config()
       self.pack()

       self.main_frame = Tkinter.Frame(self.master)

       self.button_scroll_bar = Tkinter.Scrollbar(
           self.main_frame,
           orient='vertical')

       self.button_canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(
           self.main_frame,
           yscrollcommand=self.button_scroll_bar.set,
           relief='flat',
           borderwidth=0)

       self.button_canvas.bind('<MouseWheel>', self._on_mousewheel)
       self.button_scroll_bar.config(command=self.button_canvas.yview)

       self.button_scroll_bar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
       self.button_canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

       for i in range(0, 15):
           for j in range(0, 2):
               b = Tkinter.Button(
                   self.button_canvas,
                   text='Text')

               # note we are separating the buttons 80 units horizontally
               # and 30 units vertically...I just chose these numbers
               # since they looked reasonable.
               self.button_canvas.create_window(
                   (80 * j),
                   (30 * i),
                   anchor='nw',
                   window=b
               )
       # here we need to update the scrollregion, notice the same x, y numbers
       # multiplied times the number of buttons we placed in the canvas
       self.button_canvas.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, 80*2, 30*15))

       self.main_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

   def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
       self.button_canvas.yview_scroll(-event.delta, "units")

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Title Here')

w = 512
h = 256

app = Application(root, width=w, height=h)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks Fiver, This helped a lot